# how to remove elements with multiplication array value?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have one multiplication associative array where I have four values. Following I have the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Morning Ride
            [distance] => 1723.3
            [type] => Ride
            [id] => 2011096935
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Evening Walk
        [distance] => 3165.5
        [type] => Walk
        [id] => 2008414015
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Morning walk
        [distance] => 2262.9
        [type] => Walk
        [id] => 1963423515
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => Evening Runining
        [distance] => 531.2
        [type] => Run
        [id] => 1951087309
    )
)
```

In the array there is value "type" where one is Ride, one is Run and two is for Walk. Now my concern is I want only Walk type value in array not all value. So How can I do this.

I am using one function for this:

```
function removeElementWithValue($array, $key, $value){
     foreach($array as $subKey => $subArray){
          if($subArray[$key] == $value){
               unset($array[$subKey]);
          }
     }
     return $array;
}
$activities = removeElementWithValue($stravaactvity, "type", 'Run');
```

this only remove the my Run type value not Ride one also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to keep `Walk` you could also use [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) instead of removing the others.

```
$res = array_filter($arrays, function($x) {
    return $x["type"] === "Walk";
});

print_r($res);
```

See a [php demo](https://3v4l.org/Xlr7f)

Comment: Your answer is perfect for my requirements. Thanks, buddy. One more addition, Can we filter with distance also, If i need array who is greater than value 2500 in distance type.

Answer (score 0):

Just run your function again with your other value as well.

```
function removeElementWithValue($array, $key, $value){
     foreach($array as $subKey => $subArray){
          if($subArray[$key] == $value){
               unset($array[$subKey]);
          }
     }
     return $array;
}
$activities = removeElementWithValue($stravaactvity, "type", 'Run');
$activities = removeElementWithValue($activities, "type", 'Ride');
```